# It does not add to an arrayList for some reasons

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got this strange thing, I'm trying to add to the ArrayList but it does not add, it get the values and everything. Please check the code and brigthen me up.

The class where I am trying to add:

```
public class ManualProductGUI extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField barcodeField;
private JTextField idField;
private JTextField nameField;
private JTextField priceField;
private JTextField quantityField;
private JTextField infoField;

BasketContainer bc = new BasketContainer();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ManualProductGUI dialog = new ManualProductGUI();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public ManualProductGUI() {
    setTitle("Product search");
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);


    barcodeField = new JTextField();
    barcodeField.setText("Enter barcode");
    barcodeField.setBounds(10, 11, 157, 20);
    contentPanel.add(barcodeField);
    barcodeField.setColumns(10);
    barcodeField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            barcodeField.setText("");
        }
    });

    barcodeField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int barcode = Integer.parseInt(barcodeField.getText());
            ProductCtr prodCtr = new ProductCtr();

            Product prod = prodCtr.searchProductByBarcode(barcode);
            buildFields(prod);
        }
    });

    infoField = new JTextField();
    infoField.setEditable(false);
    infoField.setBounds(177, 133, 86, 20);
    contentPanel.add(infoField);
    infoField.setColumns(10);
    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            JButton okButton = new JButton("Add");
            okButton.setActionCommand("Add");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    addToBasket();
                    setVisible(false);
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        }
        {
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
        }
    }
}

private void addToBasket()
{
    int barcode = Integer.parseInt(barcodeField.getText());
    ProductCtr prodCtr = new ProductCtr();

    Product prod = prodCtr.searchProductByBarcode(barcode);

    bc.addProduct(prod);
}
```

}

And here is a part of the Container class:

```
private ArrayList<Product> listOfItems;
public BasketContainer()
{
    listOfItems = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addProduct(Product prod)
{
    listOfItems.add(prod);
}
public ArrayList<Product> getProducts()
{
    return listOfItems;
}
```

It prints out the info on the screen, but it does not add. Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: you'll want to add the generic type to the instantiation of listOfItems, too `listOfItems = new ArrayList<Product>()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You create a new instance of `BasketContainer` every time, so that new instances will have a new clear ArrayList.

To fix it you should create your `BasketContainer` instance somewhere (maybe in an init block?) and save the reference, then use it to add the elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I did exactly as you said, I put the `BasketContainer` in an Init block, but it didn't fixed my problem. Maybe you can advise some more? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your changed code? And, Where is addToBasket method?

Comment: I edited my post, added the whole class. Notifing you because I do not know if it notifies when my post is edited.

Comment: How you read the list? And where? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: From the container class(I edited and added the method how I read it). Sorry for not being so specific in the very first.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong right now, where you call getProducts?

Comment: I call it from the other class by using `System.out.println(bc.getProducts);` just to check.

Comment: Can you post this code block too? It's the same bc instance of ManualProductGUI?

Comment: its in another class, I put the `BasketContainer bc = new BasketContainer();` in the init just like in the `ManualProductGUI`.
`btnAs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){    System.out.println(bc.getProducts());
}
});`

Comment: It didn't work because you update an ArrayList in a class, then you create a new in another class. You need to share the same bc instance. Or update the list in the other class. Or create a method which update the arraylist of the other class from ManualProductGUI

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `BasketContainer` within the scope of the method.

```
BasketContainer bc = new BasketContainer();
bc.addProduct(prod);
```

The `addToBasket` method should call `addProduct` on a field of the class it's in.